# How to use App Framework panelload in Intel XDK

Tags: intel-xdk, appframework

I tried to use panelload, but it won't trigger in my app, here is my code, any one can help?

```js
    $(document).on("loadpanel","#uib_page_1", function(evt){
        alert("Test");
    });
```

```html
    <div class="upage vertical-col left view" id="mainpage" data-header="none" data-footer="none">
      <div class="pages">
        <div class="upage-content vertical-col left panel ac0" id="uib_page_1">
...
          </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me on appFramework 3.0 :

```
   $(document).on("panelload","#uib_page_1", function(){
        console.log("Test");
    });
```